# Approval Process

Tags: approval-process

I have a requirement in approval process that I want dynamic approvers in UNANIMOUS approval based on some values. Suppose if condtion is "A" then I want UNANIMOUS approval of any 3 users and if condition is "B" then I want UNANIMOUS approval of any other 5 users. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Praveen. A couple of things to clarify: unanimous means all, so if condition is A do you mean that you want *all 3* approvers, or just that you need *any 3* approvers? And is it the same for condition B?

Comment: Hi Mike, the scenario is like, suppose for a step we require unanimous approval and the step is compulsory. But, a condition will decide that at this step how many approvers are required for unanimous approval. So suppose there are 3 approvers whose unanimous approval is required based on formula fields that populate YES/NO based on some condition. So for this I have to create about 2^3 steps for this.

Comment: These formula fields basically represents an approver. So if a field is YES then the respective approver is required in unanimous approval in the step otherwise not.